# Chef - Pass value from one resource to other resource

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra

here is a piece of my chef ruby code and I am trying to pass a value from one block to other  block.
We have multiple ports running on the server, below code will check the port and if its not running it will try to execute the 2nd block. I have attached the code and error. Please help where i am going wrong.

```
ports.each do |port|
  bash "Check_port_running_#{port}" do
   code <<-EOH
     pidval=$(ps -ef | grep /opt/redis/src/redis-server | grep *:#{port} | grep -vc grep)
     if (($pidval == 0));then
       portval_#{port}=true
     else
       portval_#{port}=false
     fi
   EOH
  end

  bash "Starting_redis_after_crash_for_port - #{port}" do
    only_if { "portval_#{port}" }
    code <<-EOH
      rm -f #{port}.pid
      sudo service redis@#{port} start
    EOH
  end
end
```

Error : Getting below error

```
       ================================================================================
       Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[Starting_redis_after_crash_for_port - 54321]'
       ================================================================================

       Errno::ENOENT
       -------------
       No such file or directory - portval_54321

       Resource Declaration:
       ---------------------
       # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/csg_orderservices_redis/recipes/configure.rb

       184:   bash "Starting_redis_after_crash_for_port - #{port}" do
       185:     only_if "portval_#{port}"
       186:     code <<-EOH
       187:       rm -f #{port}.pid
       188:       sudo service redis@#{port} start
       189:     EOH
       190:   end
       191: end

       Compiled Resource:
       ------------------
       # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/csg_orderservices_redis/recipes/configure.rb:184:in `block in from_file'

       bash("Starting_redis_after_crash_for_port - 54321") do
         action [:run]
         default_guard_interpreter :default
         backup 5
         interpreter "bash"
         declared_type :bash
         cookbook_name "csg_orderservices_redis"
         recipe_name "configure"
         code "      rm -f 54321.pid\n      sudo service redis@54321 start\n"
         domain nil
         user nil
         only_if "portval_54321"
       end
```

Comment: The `only_if` guard should evaluate to `true/false`. You probably need an expression to compare it and return true or false status.

Comment: Or are you expecting to find a file with that name (as per error)?

Comment: nope .. i am not expecting any file.. not sure why getting no directory or file found,

Comment: So when you use `only_if`, what condition are you trying to match with `portval_#{port}`?

Comment: trying to get true or false value from 1st block.

Comment: I get it. The variable set within `bash` block is becoming a Shell variable, and my guess is that, it is not known as a Ruby/Chef variable.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be to avoid using bash resources for this. This is to ensure your Chef recipes are idempotent, and can simplify your code as most of the heavy lifting is done by the Chef client. I only use bash, powershell, etc. resources as a last resort.

Here's my suggestion and example below:

Create a library file called redis.rb in your libraries folder within the cookbook. I prefer to namespace my libraries to help organize my methods. This `redis_active?` method can be used from anywhere in your cookbook where this module is included.

**libraries/redis.rb:**

```
# Replace CookbookName with actual cookbook name

module CookbookName
  module Redis
    include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

    def redis_active?(port)
      cmd = "ps -ef | grep /opt/redis/src/redis-server | grep *:#{port} | grep -vc grep"
      pid_exists = shell_out(cmd).stdout.strip.to_i

      return true if pid_exists > 0
    end
  end
end
```

In your redis recipe, the `file` resource will only take action if the `redis_active?` method returns false for the specified port, and then `file` resource will converge and remove the pid file. When this resource converges, it will notify the `service` resource to restart the redis server service immediately.

**recipes/redis.rb:**

```
# Replace CookbookName with actual cookbook name

Chef::Resource::File.send(:include, CookbookName::Redis)

ports.each do |port|
  file "/path/to/#{port}.pid" do
    action :delete
    not_if { redis_active?(port) }
    notifies :restart, "service[redis@#{port}]", :immediately
  end

  service "redis@#{port}" do
    action :nothing
  end
end
```